Is there any way to call APIs using RPA through the OpenRPA app/framework
Calling APIs through a RPA flow is the primary problem as I am exploring OpenRPA and it does not have an innate functionality to call APIs.
I have been exploring RPA through OpenRPA to automate a few tasks. While working I was wondering how to call APIs. After exploring the OpenRPA community, I found that NodeRED can be used to call APIs, however NodeRED is no longer available on OpenRPA. I read in a few places that NodeRED could still be used but was unable to figure out how.
Has anyone figured out how to call APIs through OpenRPA or through other RPA platforms?
It will be helpful if you could guide me through the process.

Why UIPath tag?

You could host your own instance of NodeRED on a local machine or a VPS machine in cloud.
You also need to create and expose some REST endpoints on your OpenRPA with OpenFlow so you have a point of communication between NodeRED and OpenRPA.
Keep in mind that security would be key here as you don't want anything except your NodeRED machine accessing your APIs and OpenRPA.
